# fusion charts show Export Dialog not showing in javascript

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

Hi I am using fusion charts (using Javascript not flash). Charts are working fine. Then I export the chart as image/pdf , this works fine.
In fusion charts there is an option to show a dialog box (progess bar) like this that says Capturing data. I also want to show this dialog box but its not coming.

Here is the link of dialog box (progess bar ) http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/exporting-image/Images/SAI_Progress.jpg

I have included these javascript files - 
FusionCharts.js
FusionChartsExportComponent.js
and I am returning this kind of xml from my server and this xml is parsed by client side javascript. Everything (chart creation , save as image/pdf ) works fine except the progress bar.

Sorry If still I am not clear.

```
<chart exportEnabled ='1'
       showExportDialog='1'
       exportDialogMessage='Capturing Data :'
       exportDialogColor='e1f5ff'
       exportDialogBorderColor='0372ab'
       exportDialogFontColor='0372ab'
       exportDialogPBColor='0372ab'
       exportAtClient='0'
       exportAction='save'
       exportHandler='/fusion_exporter/index.php'
       xAxisName='01 Jan 2013 01:00 AM -- 2013-07-01 11:00 AM'
       numberPrefix="u20ac"
       showValues='0'
       showLegend='1'>
    <set label='Report data - 2' value='88348.39' />
    <set label='Report data - 1' value='59989.51' />
</chart>
```

Answer (score 1):

The exporting of FusionCharts XT Flash variant is a pixel-by-pixel capturing process that takes a while to happen when you hit export. To give users the indication that it is taking a while, a progress-bar is displayed.

For the JavaScript Charts, the export process is almost instantaneous and as such this capture-process dialog box is not displayed. That's a good thing isn't it?

In case you still want to show a message on the chart, you can use an internal API to do the same. It's not yet official (as of 3.3.1 release) and future versions may have this elevated or deprecated. :)

```
myChartInstance.ref.showChartMessage(message:string, 
    modal:boolean, cancelable:boolan);
```

Here's a link to a fiddle explaining how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/shamasis/WzNKT/

PS: Since it's for internal use, the API has it's quirks, like hiding a message causes chart's to re-animate. Nevertheless, for it may just work for your particular use-case. Also, the  equivalent API for Flash variant of charts does not support modal dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

"Capturing Data" progress bar is not visible while exporting JavaScript charts because FusionCharts Flash Export component currently does not have an equivalent JavaScript fallback. FusionCharts Export Component helps you configure the functional and visual parameters of Export Component.During export of the pure JavaScript charts, the chart data is sent to external servers for processing and converting to image/PDF.

Comment: Thanks !! 

So Its not possible to show dialog saying "Capturing data" in Fusion Charts using javascript ?
Any other way ?